# How install yii2 with vagrant on windows 10?

Tags: yii2, vagrant

when I run `E:\dvv\www\yii2progect>vagrant up`
I see error

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:47:in `[]=': Invalid argument - ruby_setenv(VAGRANT_NO_PLUGINS) (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:47:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:36:in `each_index'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:36:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it

I need install additional plugins

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest

vagrant plugin install vagrant-cachier
```